# How to compile C/C++ in Netbeans7.1.1 with GNU on remote host

Tags: c++

I have installed Netbeans 7.1.1 connecting to a remote build host (my virtual box).
I tried to compile some program I found on certain website.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/parserInternals.h>

// Appelée à la rencontre de chaque balise ouvrante
void debut_element(void *user_data, const xmlChar *name, const xmlChar **attrs) {
printf("Début de l'élément : %s\n", name);
}

int main() {
// Initialisation à zéro de tous les membres (NULL pour un pointeur par conversion)
xmlSAXHandler sh = { 0 };

// Affectation des fonctions de rappel
sh.startElement = debut_element;

xmlParserCtxtPtr ctxt;
// Création du contexte
if ((ctxt = xmlCreateFileParserCtxt("catalogue.xml")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Erreur lors de la création du contexte\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
// Fonctions de rappel à utiliser
ctxt->sax = &sh;
// Analyse
xmlParseDocument(ctxt);
// Le document est-il bien formé ?
if (ctxt->wellFormed) {
    printf("Document XML bien formé\n");
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Document XML mal formé\n");
    xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
// Libération de la mémoire
xmlFreeParserCtxt(ctxt);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, I got this error message during compilation

```
Copying project files to /home/saebyuk/.netbeans/remote/redHat/saebyuk-pc-Windows-x86/ at saebyuk@redHat
"/usr/bin/gmake" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/home/saebyuk/.netbeans/remote/redHat/saebyuk-pc-Windows-x86/C/Users/saebyuk/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml_decoder_Red_hat'
"/usr/bin/gmake"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/xml_decoder_red_hat
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/home/saebyuk/.netbeans/remote/redHat/saebyuk-pc-Windows-x86/C/Users/saebyuk/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml_decoder_Red_hat'
gmake[2]: Warning: File `main.cpp' has modification time 2.1e+04 s in the future
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -I/usr/include/libxml2 -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/xml_decoder_red_hat build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o  
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
/home/saebyuk/.netbeans/remote/redHat/saebyuk-pc-Windows-x86/C/Users/saebyuk/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml_decoder_Red_hat/main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `xmlCreateFileParserCtxt'
/home/saebyuk/.netbeans/remote/redHat/saebyuk-pc-Windows-x86/C/Users/saebyuk/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml_decoder_Red_hat/main.cpp:40: undefined reference to `xmlParseDocument'
/home/saebyuk/.netbeans/remote/redHat/saebyuk-pc-Windows-x86/C/Users/saebyuk/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml_decoder_Red_hat/main.cpp:46: undefined reference to `xmlFreeParserCtxt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/xml_decoder_red_hat] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/home/saebyuk/.netbeans/remote/redHat/saebyuk-pc-Windows-x86/C/Users/saebyuk/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml_decoder_Red_hat'
gmake[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/saebyuk/.netbeans/remote/redHat/saebyuk-pc-Windows-x86/C/Users/saebyuk/Documents/NetBeansProjects/xml_decoder_Red_hat'
gmake: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I know this has been asked thousands of times here but I couldn't find the correct answer.
Appreciate if anyone of you could guide me as I am new in this.

Comment: Does `/usr/include/libxml2` exist on the remote system?

Comment: None of your output shows `-lxml2` -- are you confident in your `Makefile`?

Comment: well, i am new in this and i have no idea how to make the linkage and all :(
so, i am not really confident on my Makefile..do I have to configure anything from my netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to configure Netbeans; but your code compiles without trouble if you execute this command by hand:

```
gcc -o xmltest xmltest.c -I /usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2
```

If you don't yet have a `Makefile`, this is a good start:

```
LDFLAGS := -I /usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2
```

But, if Netbeans forces you to use a different build system, you'll have to figure out another way to set the linker options appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for help sarnold!
I am missing the LDFLAGS - "-lxml2" part.
After set it in Netbeans, it works!

Answer (score 0):

The libxml2 library is under libxml2/libxml/* but all the header files are using libxml/*.

Changing the directive to

```
#include <libxml2/libxml/*>
```

will also complain because all the directives are pointing to the same folder; a work around I did, on the remote server, was to create a symbolic link to the library under the include folder.

Debian Lenny on a ARM board...

```
ln -s /usr/include/libxml2/libxml /usr/include/libxml
```

Restarted Netbeans, all the red went away, the build was successful and ran successfully.